# React & es6 : Conditional rendering in a return

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

First, I check if I'm in edit or create mode then I want to hide some field if I'm in edit mode :

```
 render() {
    const isEdit = activity ? 'EDIT' : 'ADD';    
    return ({if (isEdit === 'ADD') {
       <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
          <Field
             name="opportunityContactEmail"
             fullWidth
             component={TextField}
             floatingLabelText={renderLabel('ACTIVITY_ADMIN_FORM_EMAIL')}
           />                
       </div>
    }
 }
```

But it's not working, what the best solution for this ?

Comment: `isEdit = 'ADD'` is an assignation of a value to a variable, not a boolean operator. `if (isEdit = 'ADD')` seems very wrong.

Comment: your `const` and `if` statement could be rewritten as `if (!activity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return !activity && <div ....>...</div>
```

Or you can do:

```
render() {
  if (activity) return null;
  return <div ....>...</div>;
}
```

Not sure where your `activity` is declared though. It should probably be a state/prop.